# References to let me know about current directions of research in arithmetic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I have knowledge of basic algebraic geometry and good deal of number theory. I have studied roth theorem and I am currently studying proof of Mordell-Weil theorem. These two topics come under arithmetic geometry.

I am interested in doing research in Arithmetic geometry.

> For that, I request you to give references of articles written ( if any) on what are various possible directions for research in Arithmetic Geometry.( If there are some books/ blogs/papers about the survey of this field, they are also most welcome).

I shall be really grateful for any help received.

Comment: Something like [Open Problems in Arithmetic Algebraic Geometry](https://www.amazon.com/Problems-Arithmetic-Algebraic-Geometry-Mathematics/dp/1571463739)?

Comment: This is a very broad question, so I'm not sure you will find a satisfactory answer. For some people, 'arithmetic geometry' means rational points (existence/non-existence questions, or asymptotic counts), but for others it may mean Galois representations, Shimura varieties, or any part of the Langlands programme. There are many other topics that I forgot to list.